# How can you reliably predict how many executors Spark will give you when dynamic allocation is enabled?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have dynamic allocation enabled on a 10 worker node cluster. I am running tests to better understand how spark manages memory.

Each worker node has 8 vCores and `12g` of available memory according to the Spark Resource Manager. I decided to turn down the `spark.executor.memory` to `1g` and set the number of executor cores at `4`.

From this configuration I would expect each worker node to get `2` executors since `8 vCores / 4 executor cores = 2 executors`.

However, I get the following distribution from the Resource Manager:

[Resources used per node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IKYi.png)

As you can see different nodes use different numbers of executors from `2` all the way to `8`, totalling `39 executors`. How can you reliably predict how many executors Spark will give you when dynamic allocation is enabled?

Comment: `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=infinity` is the default config. If you want a reliable number, then hard-cap it.

Comment: @cricket_007 Good to know. I'm still confused as to how it is able to assign that many executors when it is using 4 cores per executor. Do you have any insight?

Comment: Like your previous question, a vCore is virtual, and does not map exactly to physical hardware. If you have 8 vCores per node, and 10 nodes, you have 80 vCores available The default value `spark.executor.cores` in cluster mode is 1. If I had to guess, your setting isn't getting applied